# Debugger for Chrome. После обновления до 4.12.9 перестал работать

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

launch.json:

```
{
    // Используйте IntelliSense, чтобы узнать о возможных атрибутах.
    // Наведите указатель мыши, чтобы просмотреть описания существующих атрибутов.
    // Для получения дополнительной информации посетите: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        // "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }]
}
```

После обновления до 4.12.9 получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если сделать откат на предыдущую версию, все опять работает. Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался. Что и где нужно донастроить?

Comment: Расширение попросту еще не приспособили к новой версии видимо. Что поделать, так бывает \_(о_о)_/

Comment: Ответ заставил задуматься. Речь идет об обновлении именно расширения. Предыдущая версия расширения работает, после его обновления появляется вот такая ошибка. Возможно нужна где-то дополнительная настройка, не хотелось бы оставаться на старой версии.